# Parallax Background Image Full Size (Width)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I tried a long time to figure out how to make the background image of

```
<div id="information" class="intro-section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

to be covering the full-width of the browser's screen. I always get a padding that is even changing upon resizing. I tried to change the CSS style all over the place but it just does not work. I am using Bootstrap as an external link to a server, I don't have the files on my web server.

You can check out my website at [www.careerharbour.co.uk](http://www.careerharbour.co.uk) to see what I mean. There is always a padding between the width of the background picture and the screen of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either modify the CSS rules on `#container1` or `container` class or move the divs, that you wish to be full width, outside of the container div.

Your current Bootstrap container class padding:

```
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to reduce that 15px padding on both side, don't need to edit css,

wrap that container class with `<div class=row"></div>`

or if you need that image in full screen in all view-port, you can use `container-fluid` and `row-fluid` suitably.

Comment: I did that but it does not change much, in fact it changes the picture's border but somehow it does not deliver the whole size background picture as I want it.

Comment: @Xiangyu John Wu :- You need to show that balloon image in full width, for all screens ? or just maintain the size and reduce only padding?

Comment: I wish to have it full size in the width, touching directly the screen without ever having any padding left or right but it should be a parallax image so when you scroll down, it disappears. I will actually redo the whole code now. I think something just broke in my code, don't know what but I made a lot of experiment so maybe something is conflicting.

Comment: For that you need to use `container-fluid` class out side the `container` class. Because `container` class is only 1173px. max. `container-fluid` is full width and you can write the code like this

`<div id="container3" class="container-fluid">
        <div id="information" class="intro-section">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>`
 and remove the `position:relative` from `#information`

Comment: Ok, I actually re-wrote the whole code. It did not take too long I will upload today in a few hours. Right now it is under: www.careerharbour.co.uk/testing/index.html